# How do I scan in a text file using the scanner class and then make a string of that text file?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG6Hj.png)I am in an intro to programming class and can only have a program using the scanner class and the filereader class. Currently I keep getting errors when I try to create the scanner and get it to scan the text file into a string.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
                                              public class ReadingLevelThree
{
                                              public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("required.txt");
    String text = scan.("required.txt");
    System.out.println(text);   
   }
}

Comment: So far I've tried that, but I keep getting an error that an identifier was expected when I put that the String text = scan.("required.txt")

Comment: Please add code, as well as errors that you are seeing.  That way we can help you much better.

Comment: Add the code to your post and we can help you in answer. You have 2 problems, if you want to read from file, initialize `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("required.txt"));`, to read line `String text = scan.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I assume you want to use the Scanner Class in java which gives the keyboard access to input.... 
Here is an example of how you can use the Scanner Class in Java.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    public class test{
        public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How was your day today?");
        String input = kbReader.next();
    }
}
```

Okay so first make sure you import the extra tools which is the java.util.*; (when you add "*" to the end of it imports all of the tools) and make sure you use "kbReader.next()" when it is a string and you can use it to enter "int", "double", etc by adding int and double to the end like this

```
int x = kbReader.nextInt();
```

make sure it is capitalized

This is how you use the scanner class to make a string of text

Answer (score 0):

You can see in below program. I use a delimiter(\Z) in scanner class that used to scan the file up to end of file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReadingWithScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file=new File("D:\\FileBrowser2.java");
        String txt = "";
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(file);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        txt = sc.next();
        System.out.println(txt);
    }
}
```